# You are loading data without specifying data format, data will be treated as CSV format by default

Tags: google-apps-script, google-bigquery

Im trying to load data by BigQuery.job to BQ table.I have array with objects.Object is built in that way

```
let word = 
{
fullWord: string,
generationType: string
}
```

So then i transform this array in to newBlob();

And using this data,and job which is already configurated im trying to run this job;

```
var data = Utilities.newBlob(generatedWordsArray.toString(), "application/octet-stream");
job = BigQuery.Jobs.insert(job, projectID, data);
```

Script works,no errors.But table continue be empty.In the project history i found job info,and found error:

```
You are loading data without specifying data format, data will be treated as CSV format by default. 
If this is not what you mean, please specify data format by --source_format.
```

I am confused,because I specified format while creating a blob("application/octet-stream").
What should i do,or where i have a mistake?

Comment: `application/octet-stream` simply means "bytes"; it does not specify a format at all.

Comment: oh,sorry for my unknowledge.How should i specify format?

Comment: I also took info from here 
https://github.com/googleworkspace/apps-script-samples/blob/master/advanced/bigquery.gs